# iOS background push notifications not triggering didReceiveNotification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to use periodic push notifications to app in background to trigger it to contact server. I'm using "content-available":1 in the message body to silently activate app in background (without raising notification and requiring user action).

This works fine most of the time, however, on some devices, while the app is in the background, this stops working: notification arrives (badge gets updated), but unless the app is in the foreground it will not trigger

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
```

(I have added logging last time this method was called...)

1. Any ideas why the system stops notifying the app in the background?
2. Is there some limit on how often this is used?
3. Maybe the app is penalized for perhaps failing to call fetchCompletion handler in timely manner? (due to a bug perhaps)